# Overlapping registers error

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86, g++, inline-assembly

Inline assembly code substitutes a C++ statement inside one of the for loops.

Sometimes it magically works and produces the right result - array sorted with radix sort. The other time Xcode generates an `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1eccccccccd)` error which I traced back to `incq (%[count], %%rdx, 4)` line using disassembly view.

**What I understand**

Disassembly views `incq (%[count], %%rdx, 4)` as `incq (%rax,%rdx,4)`. That probably means the same register is used for different operands (`%%rax` already used on `movq (%[array], %%rcx, 4), %%rax` line) and the issue lies here `:: [array] "r" (array), [count] "r" (count), "b" (digit), "c" (i)`.

**What I do not understand**

How to manage registers so that I have enough of them at my disposal (assigning to input operands and later in body code) and they don't overlap at the same time. I tried several combinations but none of them worked.

```
void countingSort(int array[], int length, int digit) {
    int i, count[10] = { };
    int sorted[length];

    // Store number of occurrences in count[].
    // for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    //     count[ (array[i] / digit) % 10 ]++;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        asm volatile (
                      "movq (%[array], %%rcx, 4), %%rax \n\t"

                      "xorq %%rdx, %%rdx \n\t"
                      "divq %%rbx \n\t"
                      "movq $10, %%rbx \n\t"
                      "xorq %%rdx, %%rdx \n\t"
                      "divq %%rbx \n\t"

                      "incq (%[count], %%rdx, 4) \n\t"

                      :: [array] "r" (array), [count] "r" (count), "b" (digit), "c" (i)
                      : "memory"
        );

    // ...
}
```

Full code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(int array[], int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        cout << array[i] << " ";
}

int findMax(int array[], int length) {
    int max = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
        if (array[i] > max)
            max = array[i];
    return max;
}

void countingSort(int array[], int length, int digit) {
    int i = 0, count[10] = { };
    int sorted[length];

    // Store number of occurrences in count[].
    // for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    //     count[ (array[i] / digit) % 10 ]++;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        asm volatile (
                      "movq (%[array], %%rcx, 4), %%rax \n\t"

                      "xorq %%rdx, %%rdx \n\t"
                      "divq %%rbx \n\t"
                      "movq $10, %%rbx \n\t"
                      "xorq %%rdx, %%rdx \n\t"
                      "divq %%rbx \n\t"

                      "incq (%[count], %%rdx, 4) \n\t"

                      :: [array] "r" (array), [count] "r" (count), "b" (digit), "c" (i)
                      : "memory"
        );

    // Change count[i] so that count[i] now contains actual
    // position of the digit in sorted[].
    // for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    //     count[i] += count[i - 1];

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        count[i] += count[i - 1];

    // Build the sorted array.
    for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sorted[count[ (array[i] / digit) % 10 ] - 1] = array[i];
        count[ (array[i] / digit) % 10 ]--;
    }

    // Copy the sorted array to array[].
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        array[i] = sorted[i];
}

void radixSort(int array[], int length) {
    // Maximum number helps later when counting number of digits.
    int max = findMax(array, length);

    // Do Counting sort for every digit.
    for (int digit = 1; max / digit > 0; digit *= 10)
        countingSort(array, length, digit);
}

int main() {
    int array[] = { 2, 4928, 48, 72, 280, 4, 66, 3, 1, 0, 4829 };
    int length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    radixSort(array, length);
    print(array, length);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forget to add clobbered registers to your clobbered list.

Comment: @liliscent yep, you're right. Adding `"rax", "rdx"` to the clobbered list fixed the error but somehow altered the loop itself. Instead of sorted `{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 48, 66, 72, 280, 4928, 4829 }` array now the output is `{ 72 4928 4928 4829 4928 4928 0 4928 4829 4928 4928 }`. Could you see any reason why this happened?

Comment: Your data size is wrong, `int` should have `d` suffix, not `q`. Especially the first `movq`, will move next `int` to the high part of `rax`.

Comment: You should always state which processor you are using as assembly languages are specific to a processor.  For example, MIPS, ARM and x86 have different assembly languages.

Comment: Why inline asm in the first place? Why not just write this as C++ and let the compiler deal with it? It'll probably generate as-good or better asm anyway (when optimization is turned on).

Comment: My last comment, `int` is `l` not `d`... typo...

Comment: @liliscent I previously tried to use `l` suffix but Xcode every time responded with `Base register is 64-bit, but index register is not` error for `mov` and `inc` instructions. I assumed assembler placed `"r" (array)` and `"r" (count)` in 64-bit registers so that I ought to change others to 64-bit as well.

Comment: @AntonTimofeev If you change suffix, you need to change register name correspondingly. For your current one, change your first `movq` to `movsl` will work.

Comment: @liliscent of course, changed `r**` registers to `e**` ones, `movq` to `movsl` but it didn't work. `movsl (%[array], %%ecx, 4), %%eax` and `incl (%[count], %%edx, 4)` keep generating the same error.

Comment: @JesperJuhl unfortunately my uni assignment is quite specific on using inline assembly 

Comment: @AntonTimofeev `movsl` is special, you can't change the name, just `"movsl (%[array], %%rcx, 4), %%rax \n\t"`. You really need to read some tutorial....

Comment: On an unrelated note. You use a variable length array (VLA). VLA's aren't allowed by C++ standards (G++ supports them as an extension).In your code the VLA is here `int sorted[length];` If targeting standard compliant C++ you could include the `vector` header and do `std::vector<int> sorted(length);`

Comment: @liliscent it's not like I'm against it, just didn't find anything about `movsl` in [GNU GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/index.html) I'm reading right now. Could you send a link so I can read more about it? Thanks.

Comment: @liliscent : MOVSL is one of the string instructions that moves a long. Did you mean [MOVSXD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSX:MOVSXD.html) that moves a 32-bit value to a 64-bit register with sign extension? Or _MOVL_ that just moves 32-bits of data to a 32-bit register (CPU automatically zero extends it through the upper 32 bits of a 64-bit register automatically)

Comment: @MichaelPetch No, in clang `movsl` is just `movslq` or `movsxd` under this context. See [here](https://godbolt.org/g/erKEkU).

Answer (score 5):

It appears this is for a class assignment. In the real world [this would not be done with inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).

Problems:

- You clobber `digit` by overwriting the associated register when you move 10 to *RBX*. The *C++* compiler doesn't know this since you made no mention of *RBX* being modified in the constraints. The compiler may assume *RBX* was the same before and after your inline assembly.
- Since you are using 32-bit integers you can use long instead of quadword division.
- [*DIV*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html) is unsigned division, [*IDIV*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IDIV.html) is signed division. Your *C++* code operates on signed numbers. This really doesn't matter though since this code will crash with negative numbers in the array. If you use signed division you can sign extend *EAX* into *EDX* with [*CDQ*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CWD:CDQ:CQO.html).
- Use the assembly template to pass the divisor (10) via a register chosen by the compiler.
- You can cast `i` to a `long` type in the constraint. In 64-bit code `long` is 64-bits and will cause the compiler to use a 64-bit register by default when referenced inside the assembly template.
- Integers are 4 bytes wide, not 8. When accessing the memory associated with the integer array you want to use instructions that read 4 bytes. The *MOVQ* and *INCQ* instructions you use move 8 bytes. You'll want to consider *MOVL* and *INCL* or other equivalents that move 4 bytes. If you want to move a signed 4-byte value from memory to a 64-Bit register you can use [*MOVSXD*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSX:MOVSXD.html). In AT&T syntax it is preferable to use *MOVSLQ*/*MOVSL* or *MOVSXL* as they are understood by both CLANG and GCC/G++.
- Allow the compiler to pick registers for input and output operands when you can rather than hard code them in the assembly template. In your code the only register that is modified implicitly by one of the instructions and we can't do much about is *RDX*. Add it to the clobbers list so the compiler knows its contents may change.

The revised code could look like this:

```
    asm (
             "movslq (%[array], %[index], 4), %%rax \n\t"
             "cdq \n\t"               /* Sign extend eax into edx */
             "idivl %[digit] \n\t"    /* array[i]/digit */
             "cdq \n\t"               /* Sign extend eax into edx */
             "idivl %[divisor] \n\t"  /* (array[i] / digit) mod 10 */
             "incl (%[count], %%rdx, 4)"
              : "=m" (*(int (*)[]) count) /* instead of memory clobber */
              : [divisor] "r" (10), [array] "r" (array), [count] "r" (count),
                [digit] "r" (digit), [index] "r" ((long)i),
                "m" (*(const int (*)[]) array) /* instead of memory clobber */
              : "rax", "rdx", "cc"
    );
```

I've also removed the memory clobber and told it that the array is an output memory operand that will be modified. This is discussed in the [GCC inline assembly documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). Since there are no other side effects of the assembly template besides what are specified in the constraints and clobbers, we don't need to use `volatile`.

You could remove the first MOV instruction and use an intermediate variable. This would allow you to pass the current value at `array[i]` via the constraint via *EAX*. Since *EAX* is now in its own input/output constraint (use `+`) we can remove it from the clobbers. The code could look like:

```
    int curval;
    asm (
             "cdq \n\t"               /* Sign extend eax into edx */
             "idivl %[digit] \n\t"    /* array[i]/digit */
             "cdq \n\t"               /* Sign extend eax into edx */
             "idivl %[divisor] \n\t"  /* (array[i] / digit) mod 10 */
             "incl (%[count], %%rdx, 4)"
             : "=m" (*(int (*)[]) count), /* instead of memory clobber */
               "+&a" (curval = array[i])  /* Early clobber, we modify it
                                             before all inputs processed */
             : [divisor] "r" (10), [array] "r" (array), [count] "r" (count),
               [digit] "r" (digit), [index] "r" ((long)i)
             : "rdx", "cc"
    );
```

---

If the answer above is overly complex and you want to fix the immediate problems in your code then a minimal set of changes could look like:

```
    asm volatile (
                  "movl (%[array], %%rcx, 4), %%eax \n\t"
                  "xorq %%rdx, %%rdx \n\t"
                  "divq %%rbx \n\t"
                  "movq $10, %%rsi \n\t"
                  "xorq %%rdx, %%rdx \n\t"
                  "divq %%rsi \n\t"
                  "incl (%[count], %%rdx, 4) \n\t"
                  :: [array] "r" (array), [count] "r" (count), "b" (digit), "c" ((long)i)
                  : "memory", "rax", "rdx", "rsi"
    );
```

- We fix modifying the register containing `digit` by using another register to store 10 in to do the division. Modifying a register listed as just an input constraint may cause undefined behaviour if the optimizing compiler assumes the value of a register didn't change. It is imperative the compiler knows what has been changed.
- Since our assembly template now modifies *RAX*, *RDX*, and *RSI* we must add them to the clobber list. They need to be in the clobber list if they don't have output constraints associated with them already.
- We use the *MOVL* instruction to move a 4 byte integer from the array to *EAX*. When the destination register of an instruction is a 32-bit register the CPU automatically zero extends it to the upper 32-bits of the 64-bit register.
- *INCQ* is changed to *INCL* to update the 4 byte memory address.

---

**Notes**:

- The `"cc"` clobber is effectively ignored by *C* / *C++* when targeting x86 and x96-64 platforms. It isn't a bad idea to specify `"cc"` as a clobber if the template does clobber the flags, as is the case in this code. If anything it is a good habit to get into if you ever work on processors where the flags being modified have to be explicitly specified in the clobber list.
- If an assembly template has no output (or input/output) constraints it is implicitly volatile and the `volatile` modifier is not needed.